# How to make Ray Animation like Candy Crush Saga application using Cocos2d V3 in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have created an application similar to Candy Crush Saga application using Cocos2d V3 in iPhone and iPad. I want the ray animation on candy. The ray should passed in different directions and at different distance. I have attached the Image for the reference.

[image]

I have also the sequence of animation Images of ray like,
 [image]
 [image]
 [image] 
 [image]
 [image]
 [image]

Could any one can assist me how this can be done ?

Comment: Make a new class for the Ray and animate it like this tutorial: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/331/ccanimatedsprite-the-easiest-way-to-animate-a-spr , then you can add more rays just changing the angle, so you can face more directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the angle of rotation:

```
CGPoint difference = ccpSub(targetCloud.position, sourceCloud.position);
CGFloat rotationRadians = ccpToAngle(difference);
CGFloat rotationDegrees = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotationRadians);
rotationDegrees -= 90.0f;
CGFloat rotateByDegrees = rotationDegrees - targetCloud.rotation;
```

To find the scale :

```
float dist = ccpDistance(targetCloud.position,sourceCloud.position);
CCSprite *line = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"0_light.png"];
float scale = dist / line.boundingBox.size.width;
```

To create the animation :

```
-(CCActionSequence *)createRayAnimationFrom:(CGPoint)startPosition atAngle:(float)angle toScale:(float)scale
{
 //Using Texture packer
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"light.pvr.ccz"];
[self addChild:batchNode];


[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"light.plist"];

CCSprite *raySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"0_light.png"];
raySprite.position = startPosition;
raySprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.0);

[batchNode addChild:raySprite];

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for( int i=1;i<=12;i++)
{
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_light.png",i]];
    [animFrames addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];
animation.delayPerUnit = 0.1f;
animation.restoreOriginalFrame = YES;


    CCActionAnimate *animAction  = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
    CCActionSequence *animSequence = [CCActionSequence actions:[CCActionRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:angle],[CCActionScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.1 scaleX:1.0f scaleY:scale],animAction,[CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

        [CCActionRemove action];

    }], nil];

[raySprite runAction:animSequence];
 }
```

You have to call this function for each target cloud:

```
[self createRayAnimationFrom:sourceCloud atAngle:rotateByDegrees toScale:scale];
```